# Call Swift functions by inserting characters in the function call

Tags: swift

If I have these two functions:

```
func f_100() {

}

func f_200() {

}
```

Is it possible to change the name of the function in the call? Similar to inserting a string. Something like this:

```
let n = 100
f_"\(n)"()
```

Comment: Generally if you’re trying to do something like this, you really need an array.

Comment: @Joe are you trying to dynamically call the method by creating a string of the method name and then invoking it?

Comment: Why do you need this? Could you tell me more about your case?

Comment: No. Swift is a compiled language. You can't generate function calls by  changing strings like that. That said, there are ways to accomplish the sorts of things you want to accomplish. Tell us the end goal you're after and we can help you achieve it.